# How do I make an "else" in an IE HTML conditional?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-9

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    This is less then IE9
ELSE
    this is all browsers: firefox, chrome, etc.
<![endif]-->
```

How do I do this in my HTML? I want to do an "else" ...

Comment: There is no "else": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You're not looking for an else, you're looking for `<![if !IE]> <something or other> <!--[endif]>` (note that this is not a comment).

```
<!--[if IE]>
   You're using IE!
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
   You're using something else!
<![endif]>
```

You can find documentation on the conditional comments [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/conditionalcomments).

Comment: Can I use this to include javascript files? in other words, include a ie.js if the browser is IE, otherwise include 'all_other_browsers.js'

Comment: Yes, you can. You can place anything you want between the closing and opening tags (no nesting though...).

Comment: just note that in order to negate an ie version the condition must be in parenthesis, e.g. `<![if !(IE 7)]>`

Comment: Unfortunately, html conditional comments are not supported in IE 10, so checking `if IE` will **not** work in IE 10... see KhanSharp's answer below for a modern solution.

Comment: other browsers cannot read this...so what is the necessity of <![if !IE]>

Comment: @Liza Other browsers will ignore `<![if !IE]>` and `<![endif]>`, which means that if you want to have IE specifically *ignore* a directive you can. So, for example, this will show up in FF but not IE: `<![if !IE]>CONGRATULATIONS! Chances are you have a half-way competent team writing your browser!<![endif]>`

Comment: To do an else for higher IE version + all other browsers. You need **special syntax**: `<!--[if gt IE 8]> <!-- -->
Here is some code for anything but IE 8 and below.
<!-- <![endif]-->`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10159787/903186

Comment: @IanCampbell luckily IE10 does not require anything close to the level of shimming as the prior versions so this can be seen as a benefit (IE10 will run the ES5+ compatible JS)

Comment: Thanks @cwallenpoole, its saved my time for IE8 Vs. other browser compatibility.

Answer (score 43):

I use the following to load resources in IE9 or newer and all other browsers

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->        
    //your style or script
<!--<![endif]-->
```

This is hard to believe. Look the opening and closing if statement sections are inside comments (so, its not visible to other browsers) but visible to IE.

Comment: +1  Awesome, this actually works for IE 10 too! Checking `<!--[if lte IE 8]> ... ... <![endif]-->` *before* this should cover all conditions to check for when using CSS media queries.

Comment: Also note that *without* the `<!` immediately following the opening if statement, "-->" will appear on the page in IE 9, so you do want to include that.

Comment: This syntax `<!--[if IE]>` is not working in IE7 compatibility mode.
Use the syntax in this answer to make it work if you are unlucky enough to support IE6 :-|

Comment: Too bad Babel/webpack consider this as a SyntaxError

Answer (score 12):

The solution for your problem is (note the use of `<!-- -->`):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  This is less then IE9
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <!-- -->
  this is all browsers: IE9 or higher, firefox, chrome, etc.
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what the OP asked for but that is exactly the solution I was looking for. Unfortunately I've to change the second to [if gt IE 7]. If only Microsoft were as persistent about Browser updates as they are about OS updates our jobs would be much easier.

Answer (score 8):

conditional comments can be in scripts as well as in html-

```
/*@cc_on
@if(@_jscript_version> 5.5){
    navigator.IEmod= document.documentMode? document.documentMode:
    window.XMLHttpRequest? 7: 6;

}
@else{
    alert('your '+navigator.appName+' is older than dirt.');
}
@end
@*/
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to do an `else`.  <strike>It is implied</strike>.  So

```
// put your other stylesheets here

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    //put your stylesheet here for less than ie9
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: @pst. Perhaps a better use of words is needed.  Presumably your IE targeted styles are being dealt with in other ways in your normal stylesheets, therefore it can work in a one or the other fashion.

Comment: Since the "C" in CSS means "cascading", surely the non-IE style sheets should be *before* the IE conditional statement? Otherwise the later ones will take precedence over the previous ones and any IE specific selectors and rules they have in common.

Comment: IE conditionals were made so that IE can have its own instructions. All other browsers just see it as a plain HTML comment.

Comment: Noted @RobG. Thanks. Thought of that before I posted but... edited

Comment: @Jason Gennaro The edit is much better (also inverting the order is important in many cases.)

Comment: of course the second css will overwrite the first, if used. nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer by @cwallenpoole breaks the markup, makes HTML invalid, and breaks Visual Studio's syntax highlight.

Here's how you keep it clean:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    You're using IE!
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    You're not using IE. See, even SO highlights this correctly.
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
</head>
 <!--[if IE]>
<body style="margin: 38px 0 0 0;">
 <![endif]-->
 <!--[if !IE]>
<body>
 <![endif]-->

  -Content-

 </body>
</html>
```

This worked for me, after hours of searching. I needed the head room for a pop-up banner, that IE didn't want to animate. it was supposed to hide itself after a few seconds. Using this, I was able to just move the entire page down just enough, but only in IE, which was exactly what i needed!

Currently only for those who still use IE, I prefer FireFox or Chrome myself.

Thank you for these letters/symbols in this specific order!

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question. While this information might be helpful to someone, it is unlikely to be found when it's associated with this question.