# How do I include a javascript if it's IE, and another javascript if everything else?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-detection

I want to include `<script src="ie.js">` if the browser is IE.

Otherwise, include `all.js` for all other browsers.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this using [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).  Example:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="ie.js">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <script src="all.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks. Check out this guy's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742087/how-do-i-make-an-else-in-an-ie-html-conditional/6742121#6742121  is it the same as yours?

Comment: @TIMEX - It's very similar, yes.  Just some minor syntactic differences between the two, really.

Comment: Conditional Comments are no longer supported in IE10 and above.

Comment: That's true.  There are some good suggestions here for dealing with IE10+:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900311/how-do-i-target-only-internet-explorer-10-for-certain-situations-like-internet-e

Comment: don't forget the `</script>`.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar, and so far the simplest solution I found is to do a JS based condition to check the document.documentMode property: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_documentmode.asp

I hope this will help someone else who stumble on this thread in Google results like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments only work in IE, and are thus excellently suited to give special instructions meant only for IE. They are supported from IE 5 up until IE9 (inclusive).