# IE conditional comments 'and'?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

Is it possible to insert an 'and' in a conditional comment?

For example:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9 && if !IE]>
// MESSAGE
<![endif]-->
```

Triggering only IE 9, higher versions of IE and browsers that are not IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` operator is not even necessary. This code will run in non-IE browsers and in IE 9 and higher, according to the [syntax description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment#Downlevel-revealed_conditional_comment) on Wikipedia:

```
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
// MESSAGE
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: It appears as a comment on other browsers doesn't it?

Comment: The first and last line indeed appear as comments on other browsers. The line in between is parsed as any other HTML line. Check out the referenced Wikipedia article if you're interested in the different conditional comment techniques; it contains a nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional comments are an IE on thing.

Check out this post and answer for details on how to do what you want.

[IE Conditional Comments and Chrome/Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159642/ie-conditional-comments-and-chrome-firefox)