# conditional statement on html if IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I know html is not a programming language, however is there any way to change write code depending on browser, Doing something like:

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <section class="card-container">
    <div id="so1" class="card over"  data-direction="right">        
      <div class="front" >
         <h1></h1><br/><br/><br/>
            <h2>ie
            </h2>
            <h3></h3>
      </div>         
      <div class="back" style="background-color:#99ca3c;">
          <img src="images/fanc1.jpg" width ="100%;" height ="100%;" alt="">                    
      </div>         
    </div>
   </section>
<![endif]-->
```

IF NOT ie

```
   <section class="card-container">
    <div id="so1" class="card over"  data-direction="right">        
      <div class="front" >
    <img src="images/fanc1.jpg" width ="100%;" height ="100%;" alt="">
      </div>         
      <div class="back" style="background-color:#99ca3c;">
            <h1></h1><br/><br/><br/>
            <h2>not ie
            </h2>
            <h3></h3>               
      </div>         
    </div>
   </section>
```

Or the only way it to use php and echo specific html code?

As you can see I only need to switch what is inside front or back depending on browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An update if somebody still reaches this page, wondering why the ie targeting doesnt work. IE 10 and onward no longer support conditional comments. From the MS official website:

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
>   10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5.

Please see here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

If you desperately need to target ie, you can use this jquery code to add a ie class to  and then use .ie class in your css to target ie browsers.

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
 $("html").addClass("ie");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
  <section class="card-container">
    <div id="so1" class="card over"  data-direction="right">        
      <div class="front" >
    <img src="images/fanc1.jpg" width ="100%;" height ="100%;" alt="">
      </div>         
      <div class="back" style="background-color:#99ca3c;">
            <h1></h1><br/><br/><br/>
            <h2>not ie
            </h2>
            <h3></h3>               
      </div>         
    </div>
   </section>
<!--[endif]-->
```

Comment: So I would need 2 sections `<!--[if IE]>  IE STUFF <!--[endif]-->` and   
 `<!--[if !IE]--]> MODERN BROWSER STUFF <!--[endif]-->` right?

Comment: I believe so. It's not quite if-else but it does the same thing

Comment: Bear in mind that conditional comments (the method below to give code to IE or not) only working in IE9 and below. However, there are not many reasons why you need to special case IE10.

Answer (score 2):

The currently accepted answer didn't work for me. The

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
```

statement was visible on the page on IE8. I found the answer here: [How do I make an "else" in an IE HTML conditional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742087/how-do-i-make-an-else-in-an-ie-html-conditional)

```
<![if !IE]>
   <section class="card-container">
     Not IE
   </section>
<![endif]>
```