# can conditional comments cause a seperate style sheet to be used for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, conditional-statements

I have a page that I want to use one stylesheet for IE(all versions) and a separate stylesheet for all other browsers (firefox, safari etc).

My conditional statement within my  tags so far looks as such:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!--><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"><![endif]-->
```

I have attempted using a negative statement so that the stylesheet for IE is not overuled by the one used for the other browsers.

However this is not working, with the IE page still being styled by the style.css file, not the style2.css file.
I've checked and my file names correspond to the code, and are in the correct folders etc.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I believe you might have an extra `<!-->` on your first line. See the top answer on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742087/how-do-i-make-an-else-in-an-ie-html-conditional

Comment: aha....thanks Elise!! Sometimes the answer is staring you so obviously in the face, you dont see it :-)

Comment: @Elise - I suggest you post that as an answer. :)