# HTML text displayed twice when opening the email from Outlook

Tags: html, email, outlook, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I built an HTML block with a personalized code in the email and I would like to know why the text is displayed twice when opening the email in Outlook from a desktop device, only when using Windows OS.

```
<!--[if mso]>
        <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" style="height:42px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:218px;" arcsize="5%" strokecolor="#ffffff" fillcolor="#ffffff">
          <w:anchorlock/>
          <center style="color:#1672b9;font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif;font-size:12px; letter-spacing:1.5px; font-weight:bold;border-radius: 15px;">Personalized code</center>
        </v:rect>
      <![endif]-->
      <a style="background-color:#ffffff;border-radius: 15px;color:#1672b9 !important;display:inline-block;font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:44px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:3px;">Personalized code</a>
```

[image]

Comment: Because you have the text inside and outside the conditional comment.

Comment: Thanks, how should be the code? Sorry, I am not an HTML expert.

Comment: Do you want the second `<a>` not to appear in Outlook or the first?

Comment: Exactly, the second <a> should not appear in Outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<!--[if mso]>
  <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" style="height:42px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:218px;" arcsize="5%" strokecolor="#ffffff" fillcolor="#ffffff">
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="color:#1672b9;font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif;font-size:12px; letter-spacing:1.5px; font-weight:bold;border-radius: 15px;">Personalized code</center>
  </v:rect>
<![endif]-->
<![if !mso]>
  <a style="background-color:#ffffff;border-radius: 15px;color:#1672b9 !important;display:inline-block;font-family:'Noto Sans', sans-serif;font-size:12px;line-height:44px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all; font-weight:bold; letter-spacing:3px;">Personalized code</a>
<![endif]>
```

See also: ["How do I make an “else” in an IE HTML conditional?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6742087/9253414).

Comment: But this code will not display anything for non-Outlook inboxes, right? It is still showing the text twice in Outlook.